# DownloadManager Failed to create target file / E/cutils:|Failed to mkdirat | Failed to ensure directory |SDK<21

Tags: android, android-file, android-download-manager, android-external-storage, android-storage

I am using the following code to download a file using DownloadManager. The download works perfectly on real devices & emulators for SDK 21+.

However, on real devices & emulators with SDK 19 and below the download fails with the following error in Logcat:

**Samsung device:**

```
E/cutils: Failed to mkdirat(/storage/extSdCard/Android): Read-only file system

W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.example.downloadcatalogues/files

I/DownloadManager: Download 71 finished with status FILE_ERROR
```

**Emulator:**

```
W/DownloadManager: Failed to create target file /storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.downloadcatalogues/files/test/123.zip

I/DownloadManager: Download 71 finished with status FILE_ERROR
```

If I change the location to `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` I get the same behavior.

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
</application>
```

**Activity**

```
findViewById(R.id.extrauma_button).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String urlZipFile = "https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-large-zip-file.zip";
            downloadPro(urlZipFile, "extrauma");
            });

private void downloadPro(String url, String title){
        DownloadManager downloadManager;

    try{
        File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()+"/test/","123.zip");

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
            .setTitle(title)
            .setDescription("Downloading")Notification
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE)
            .setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(file))
           .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .setAllowedOverMetered(true)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(true);

    downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    long downloadID = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    Log.v("downloadProId", downloadID+"");
}
catch (Exception e){
    Log.w("stopped", e.toString());
}
}
```

**N.B:**
The download link works if I try it on Chrome browser on devices with SDK 19 and below!

Am I missing smth?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by using:

```
.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(),"test","123.zip")
```

instead of:

```
.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(file))
```

For some reason, the `.setDestinationUri` method does not work for pre-Lollipop.